# Bash find line of code in a file/files, in directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory

How can I go about finding the line:

```
 print("hello world)"
```

In a directory **x/y/z** where the file/files could be in any branch of **x**'s tree (where directory **x** has many children folders

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use recursive `grep` from parent directory of `x`:

```
grep -FR 'print("hello world)"' x/*
```

Comment: As the line you are looking for look like some code, you may be interested into using the flag '--include':
    grep -FR --include '*.c' 'print("hello world")' x/*
To look for c code file for instance.

Comment: Yes I would have include `--include=` as well but nothing was mentioned in question what file extensions to search for

Comment: is the `F` flag used so escaping isnt required?

Comment: Yes `F` is for fixed-string so pattern is not treated as regex.